# The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was working on visual studio 2010 on a microsoft word project but when I install visual studio 2012 it throws an exception on its build time.
The exception -

> Error 52  The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the
>    declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  IVerifySpecExcel2007

Comment: did you replace your version 10.0.0.0 in your Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets file to 11.0.0.0 ? try this.

Answer (score 1):

after replacing the version 10.0.0.0 in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.tagets file to 11.0.0.0 it build successfully